# How to eliminate the backward play in Export of Manipulate?

Tags: export, manipulate, animation

I find that the `Export` of `Manipuate` contains backforward play, see a simplified example:

```
Export["try.swf", 
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[2 x + φ], {x, 0, 10}], {φ, 0, 2 π}]]
```

You can see the problem in the SWF file. (I'm sorry that the exported SWF file cannot be uploaded here)

Actually, I have two questions here,

1. Is there any simple way to get a animation with **only forward**
   play? I can find nothing about this in the help documents.
2. Why is GIF not working in `Export`? That is to say, if I use
   `Export["try.gif", Manipulate[...]]`,the exported file, otherwise an
   animation, is only a static picture actually.

Comment: Try `Export["yourfile.gif", 
 Table[Plot[Sin[2 x + \[Phi]], {x, 0, 10}], {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi, 
   2 Pi/20}]]`

Comment: @ belisarius， you mean the gif can only be used in exporting a sequence of images?

Comment: An animated GIF is just a series of GIFs ... you have to specify them one by one, yes

Comment: There was also a way by using `Animate[]`. I don't remember it right now

Answer (score 6):

Both questions can be addressed by using a `Table` to generate the frames of the animation rather than `Manipulate`:

```
mov = Table[Plot[Sin[2 x + ϕ], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange->All], {ϕ, 0, 2 π, 
2 π/10}];
Export["movie.gif", mov]
```

[image]

Although this runs the animation in the forward direction only, it does repeat indefinitely. This technique is not limited to .gif, e.g., I use this to export .swf animations quite a bit.

You can of course control the smoothness of the animation by changing the increment 2 π/10 to something smaller if you like.

Comment: Quick comment: better to use `Export["movie.gif", Most[mov]]` because your `Table` duplicates the starting point of the periodicity interval so that the movie appears to stop briefly when it completes one loop.

Comment: Good point, although I left that repetitious frame there so he could see the animation was repeating (and when). This may not be desirable in his final application though.